# How do I locate/access PDF files generated through my app on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, reactjs, react-native, native

I'm using https://github.com/christopherdro/react-native-html-to-pdf to generate `PDF files`.
On `Android` they end up in my Download folder and all is good, on iOS however they end up in:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/xxxxxxxxxx/Documents/xxxx.pdf
```

How do users then locate the files? I assumed they would be visible in the "Files" app but they're not.
**I'm basically doing this for iOS:**

```
let options = {
  html: '<h1>PDF TEST</h1>',
  fileName: 'test',
  directory: 'Documents',
};
```

I've tried without supplying a directory, or "docs" instead of "Documents" which put them in the same place but /temp instead of /Documents.

Am I doing something wrong? How are iOS users supposed to locate/access the PDF files without having to go through a bunch of stuff to access that folder? Is it possible to make them appear in the "Files" by default?

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

You have to add "`UIFileSharingEnabled`" and "`LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace`" into your `Info.plist` with the value "YES".

That shows the documents folder for your app on an iPhone.